# Redirect all my website into https?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Im using the following in my `.httpaccess` so when a user enters to the main page of my website this be forced to load with `https`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?ka**\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.ka**.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I would like to know how can I modify this so this happen to every single page of my website, so for example, if I load `http://ka**.com/****/myfile.json` this will be forced to load with `https`.

Thanks.

Comment: rewrites use regexes. equality tests are not done with `=`. `!=` is saying "is not `=443`".

Comment: Is that `.httpaccess` just a typo? The file should be named `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't restrict your rule `^$` which is just landing page:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```